# Making cross domain AJAX requests with $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on an app using AngularJS and Phonegap. I'm trying to make a request using `$http`, however when I do I get the following error:

[image]

I have `<access origin="*"/>` in my config.xml file, so I'm not really sure what else I should change. Here is the code I use to make the request:

```
var request = $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
request.then(function(data){
  self.updateList(data);
}, function(error){
  $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Error',
    template: 'New pictures available, but we had a problem loading them. Try restarting the app.'
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I;m unfamiliar with the config but CORS is based on method & headers next to origin. Seems there is something with the 'POST' method which is not allowed. See if there's any config for 'method' and 'headers'.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP can not be used over POST, your method needs to be changed to GET.